# How can I merge route declarations (subdomain or token)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, constraints, routes

I have a model Model that can be access from many ways: by subdomain or a token

- http://model1.domain.com
- http://domain.com/j4h7

I have the following routes

```
resources :model, :constraints => {:model_id => /[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}/} do
  ... (nested resources...)
end
resources :model, :constraints => {:subdomain => /.+/} do
  ... (same as above: nested resources...)
end
```

So I currently have to duplicate all the routes for the two cases.

Is there any way to declare it only once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def nested_routes
  get :some_route
  post :some route
  resources :some_resources
end

resources :model, :constraints => {:model_id => /[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}/} do
  nested_routes
end

resources :model, :constraints => {:subdomain => /.+/} do
  nested_routes
end
```

Related topic: [Rails 3 Routes: DRY members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262988/rails-3-routes-dry-members)